# jqを使いJSONの入れ子配列から値を取得する

Tags: json, csv, jq

下記のJSONをjqでCSVに変換しています。

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"masao",
            "images":["001.jpg","002.jpg"]    
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"hideo",
            "images":["003.jpg","004.jpg"]    
        }
    ]
}
```

下記のコマンドでCSVを作成するのですが、配列の入れ子になっているimagesの情報の取得方法がわかりません。

> cat sample.json | jq -r '.items[]|[.id, .name]|@csv' | sed -e 's/"//g';
>   1,masao
>   2,hideo

どのようなコマンドを打てば
1,masao,001.jpg
2,hideo,003.jpg
のように取得することができるでしょうか？

Comment: index 付きでアクセスすれば良いような。`[.id, .name, .images[0]]|@csv`

Comment: ちなみに、`cat sample.json | jq -r '.items[]|"\(.id),\(.name),\(.images[0])"'` とすればダブルクォートが付きません。

Comment: @metropolis もしよかったら回答にかいてあげてもらえますか

Answer (score 1):

コメントにて教えていただきました。

```
cat sample.json | jq -r '.items[]|[.id, .name ,images[0]]|@csv' | sed -e 's/"//g';
```

また、`sed -e 's/"//g';`を使わなくても

```
cat sample.json | jq -r '.items[]|"\(.id),\(.name),\(.images[0])"'
```

と書けばダブルクオーテーションも取り除けるそうです。大変参考になりました。